# How do I run a python script on pypy3 without using the command line on windows 10?

Tags: python, pypy

I recently downloaded pypy3, I've never used the command line for python, I usually run my codes on visual studio code. Is there a way to use pypy3 with something similator to "IDLE Python"?

Comment: what's wrong with the command line... just use `pypy3 file_name_here.py` to run your code. I guess you could also use the Code Runner extension and then give it a command to use to run python code

Comment: Per the comment thread below @steveo314's answer about whether you're looking for a recommendation of an IDE that works with the pypy3 interpreter, or whether you're looking for how to call the pypy3 interpreter from Visual Studio Code, like you are used to doing with the CPython interpreter.

Comment: It's worth noting that the former is off-topic for Stack Overflow. And if your objective is the latter, you'll probably want to clarify the wording of your question since it's being interpreted as a request for IDEs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a change, you may use **Jupyter Notebook**.

[image]

Follow these commands on cmd for installation-

1. type 'pip3 install jupyter-notebook'
2. Once it's installed, just type 'jupyter-notebook' in cmd.

It will start the session and now you can create a Py notebook and write code Notebook cells.

The advantage of using Jupyter-Notebook is - you need not initialize variables processing repeatedly. You can just declare variable processing in different cells and consume them in some function in different one.